# Не работает соединение с сервером WebSockets

Tags: node.js, websocket

Написал простое подключение в Notepad++ к локальному адресу, но ничего не происходит. Что для этого еще нужно?

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000");
socket.onopen = function() {
alert("Соединение установлено.");
};
```

Comment: А сам сервер .js увидить можно? Дополните вопрос, слишком мало информации.

Comment: Вы не представляете, еще сервер нужен.